# Gauss' test for Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

In the text I am using, the hypotheses used for Gauss' test for convergence are different to others I have seen.

The text has the hypotheses: if the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is such that $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = 1 + \frac pn  + \alpha_n$ and the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \alpha_n$ converges absolutely, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges absolutely for $p>1$ and diverges for $p \leq 1$

Whereas elsewhere it has been: Suppose  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is a series of positive terms. Suppose there exists an integer $N \geq 1 $ such that for any $n \geq N$,

$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = 1 + \frac An  + v_n$ where $v_n$ is of order $\frac{1}{n^{1+k}},k>0$ i.e., there is a positive integer $M$ such that $|v_n| \leq C\frac{1}{n^{1+k}}$ for some positive constant $C$ and for all integers $n \geq M$.

Then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges if and only if $A>1$

Specifically these two differ in the assumption that $a_n > 0$ and in the construction of $v_n$ or $\alpha_n$ , although $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|v_n|$ should also converge as each $|v_n| \leq \frac{C'}{n^{1+k}}$, with $C' =\sup {\{C_n\}} $.

Is this simply another form of the Gauss test?